# How to fix lost time in date after converting?

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin

I want to test my `DateUtil` class and I got error - after converting my `Date` to `String` and back to Date I lost about 900 seconds.

This is my code:

```
  fun convertStringToDate() {
    // here I get current Date
    val currentDate = Date() // 1514285741928
    // see apiDateFormatter declaration below this code
    val dateStr = apiDateFormatter.format(currentDate) // Tue, 26 Dec 2017 12:55:41 GMT+02:00
    // see convertStringToDate() method declaration below this code
    val convertedDate = DateUtil.convertStringToDate(dateStr) // 1514285741000
    assertEquals(currentDate == convertedDate, true)
}
```

**apiDateFormatter**

```
val DATE_FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
val apiDateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

DateUtil.**convertStringToDate**(dateStr)

```
fun convertStringToDate(dateStr: String): Date {
    return apiDateFormatter.parse(dateStr)
}
```

The difference between `currentDate` and `convertedDate` is about 900 seconds.

Why and **how fix it**?

Comment: This isn't Java, at least not pure Java.  What language is this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, this is Kotlin. But Date class and DateFormatter from Java

Comment: `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated. Even on Android, where these may be what you get built-in, consider getting [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) so you can use JSR-310 AKA `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two UNIX epoch timestamps you have are actually in *milliseconds*, not seconds.  Here are the two values:

```
1514285741928 - before
1514285741000 - after
```

The difference between the two timestamps in 928 milliseconds.  All that has happened is that the millisecond component was truncated off.  The truncation happened when you applied a seconds-level precision date mask at this line:

```
val dateStr = apiDateFormatter.format(currentDate)
```

To get around this problem, you can try changing your `SimpleDateFormat` mask to include milliseconds:

```
val DATE_FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"
//                                           ^^^ add this
val apiDateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Comment: Tim, I got this error if there is no milisecs - java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 26 Dec 2017 12:55:41 GMT+02:00"

Comment: @Artem Tricky one.  You might have to do a little regex work to make sure you apply the right mask to each date/timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

(Java syntax, not Kotlin)

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_514_285_741_928L ) 
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
```

## java.time

As others said, your count from an epoch reference date is in milliseconds rather than whole seconds.

You are using troublesome old classes that are now outmoded by the modern java.time classes. For older Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

The java.time classes use a resolution of nanoseconds, so no problem holding your milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_514_285_741_928L ) ;
```

Or capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To see that moment in a time zone rather than UTC, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, same point in timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Tip: You are using a terrible format in your Question. For exchanging date-time values as text, use only the standard ISO 8601 formats.

Comment: Good advice. And if one needs to format the `Instant` into a string and back, one may use `Instant.toString()` and then `Instant.parse()` for getting an `Instant` again, no explicit formatter needed. Not a nanosecond will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

`Date()` will return the current time in milliseconds. But when you are converting this milliseconds into `dateString` you are eliminating the milliseconds part. So the `dateString` will not contain the milliseconds part. For this reason when you reconvert the `dateString` into `Date` object you are losing the milliseconds part or fractional part of seconds.

Lets assume current time returned by the `Date()` is `1514287787103`. After converting into string `dateString` will store `Tue, 26 Dec 2017 17:29:47` which is equvalent to `1514287787000`. Here you lost few milliseconds which leads you to the difference.

To solve this you have to consider the milliseconds portion in at the time of conversion. You can do it by simply adding the milliseconds part in `DATE_FORMAT`

`val DATE_FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"`

At the time of displaying date you can eliminate this millisecond portion but you have to consider it at the time of conversion.